# Is $\nabla=\nabla'$? Nabla operator acting on $r^n$

Tags: vectors, notation, differentiation

I have been taught that
$$\nabla r^n =\text{gradient of }r^n =n r^{n-1}\ \hat{\boldsymbol r}$$
but in introduction to electrodynamics by Griffith (4th edition) on page 173, $\nabla' r^n$ is given by $- n r^{n-1}\ \hat{\boldsymbol r}$. Is there any difference between $\nabla$ and $\nabla'$?

Comment: "Nabla" is the name of that particular triangle symbol, not the mathematical operator it represents.  The name of the operator is "del."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$r=|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}'|=\sqrt{(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2+(z-z')^2}$. We define
\begin{align}
   \nabla f(\mathbf{x}) &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \hat{i} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \hat{j} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \hat{k} \text{ and}\\
   \nabla' f(\mathbf{x}') &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x'} \hat{i} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y'} \hat{j} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z'} \hat{k}
\end{align} so $\nabla f(r)=-\nabla'f(r)$.

Comment: Could you explain how the nabla prime in the RHS came ?

Comment: Apply the definition of $\nabla'$ onto $f(r)$, compute the derivatives and compare the result with with $\nabla f(r)$.